# PySide2 polar plot axes not appearing correctly

Tags: python, pyside2, qtcharts

I'm trying to make a polar plot using QtCharts by copying the example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpolarchart.html#PolarOrientation-enum) using the source code found [linked at the bottom of that page.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtcharts-polarchart-main-cpp.html) I've converted the C++ code to PySide2 compatible code, and everything seems to mostly work (i.e. the plot shows up and the series are drawn), but for some reason, the angular axis is labelled incorrectly. When I run my code, the labels for angular axis overlap the labels for the radial axis, despite my adding the angular axis as follows:

```
self.chart.addAxis(self.angularAxis, QtCharts.QtCharts.QPolarChart.PolarOrientationAngular
```

According to the docs, this is what I'm supposed to do for the angular axis, but it doesn't seem to be working. It ends up looking like this:

[image]

Below is the code that generates this.

```
 import sys
 from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCharts

 class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
         self.angularMin = 0
         self.angularMax = 360

         self.radialMin = -100
         self.radialMax = 100

         self.chart = QtCharts.QtCharts.QPolarChart()
         self.chart.setTitle("Example Chart")

         self.angularAxis = QtCharts.QtCharts.QValueAxis()
         self.angularAxis.setTickCount(9)
         self.angularAxis.setLabelFormat("%.1f")
         self.angularAxis.setShadesVisible(True)
         self.angularAxis.setShadesBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(249, 249, 255)))
         self.chart.addAxis(self.angularAxis, QtCharts.QtCharts.QPolarChart.PolarOrientationAngular)

         self.radialAxis = QtCharts.QtCharts.QValueAxis()
         self.radialAxis.setTickCount(9)
         self.radialAxis.setLabelFormat("%d")
         self.chart.addAxis(self.radialAxis, QtCharts.QtCharts.QPolarChart.PolarOrientationRadial)

         self.radialAxis.setRange(self.radialMin, self.radialMax);
         self.angularAxis.setRange(self.angularMin, self.angularMax);

         self.chartView = QtCharts.QtCharts.QChartView(self.chart)
         self.chartView.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing);
         self.setCentralWidget(self.chartView)

 app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 main = Main()
 main.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It seems that it is a bug of PySide2 since if we print the axes with: `print(chart.axes(QtCharts.QtCharts.QPolarChart.PolarOrientationRadial))
  print(chart.axes(QtCharts.QtCharts.QPolarChart.PolarOrientationAngular))` -----> `[]`,`[<PySide2.QtCharts.QtCharts.QValueAxis object at 0x7fbf80c01a88>, <PySide2.QtCharts.QtCharts.QValueAxis object at 0x7fbf80c01ac8>]` .

Comment: [cont.] It is observed that in the radial axis there are no axes and everything is on the angular side as seen in the image. I have tested your code with pyqtChart-PyQt5 and it works correctly which reaffirms the bug, so as a recommendation report it, the problem is not your code, the problem is PySide2